# Is that right? A question regarding Spectrum of operators

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

How to show that:

A. If $X$ is a Banach space and $T\in B(X)$ then the spectrum of $T$ and $T^*$ are equal, in symbols:
$\sigma(T)=\sigma(T^*)$.

B.If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T \in  B(H)$ then the spectrum of $T^*$ is equal to the conjugate of spectrum of $T$, in symbols:
$\sigma(T^*)=\overline{\sigma(T)}$

the first part:
Using a claim that states:
If $X$ is Banach and $T \in B(X)$ then $T$ has a bounded inverse iff $T^*$ has a bounded inverse. So by the inverse bounded theorem we can conclude that (under these conditions) $T$ is invertibke iff $T^*$ is invertible.
Then by the definition of Spectrum,
$\lambda*I-T$ is invertible iff $\lambda*I-T^*$ is invertible (by above explanation) then the spectrum of $T$ and $T^*$ are equal.

Is that enough (partA)?

How to do part B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof of $A$ looks correct but there is some strange choice of wording involved. You write "If $X$ is Banach and $T \in B(X)$ then $T$ has bounded inverse iff $T^*$ has a bounded inverse" and then another sentence which is basically the same claim.

Concerning $B$, this follows from $B$ and the fact that Hilbert space comes equipped with an isomorphism between its dual space and the complex conjugate space. Note also that the meaning of $T^*$ is slightly different in this context.

Comment: Thanks @Blazej i did not much understand how I am supposed to show part B, can you extend your approach please:)

Comment: Alternatively you can proceed as in the Banach case: first show that $T \in B(H)$ is boundedly invertible if and only if $T^*$ is, then use $(T-z)^*=T^*-\overline z$.